# Sqlite exception: No such column: _collapse_libc_requires

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, exception

I have a situation where it appears that while handing an exception, the Sqlite Python code is getting the exception `no such column: _collapse_libc_requires`.

Most answers I have found for "no such column" are for SQL syntax that contains an insert, but the developer forgot to give the command string a value to insert.

But this exception appears to be in the Sqlite Python code directly. At this time I am not trying to resolve what caused the original exception. I feel like if I fix the original exception it will just hide the `no such column: _collapse_libc_requires` exception and it will just appear again in future exceptions.

So why am I getting this exception? The `_collapse_libc_requires` exception happens inside the `yum` package manager python code. It is not clear to me why `yum` would be getting an exception.

Below is the Traceback:

```
Sqlite DBs complete
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 46, in newFunc
ERROR:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 238, in _sql_MD
ERROR:     executeSQL(cur, sql, *args)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/sqlutils.py", line 168, in executeSQLQmark
ERROR:     return cursor.execute(query, params)
ERROR: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: _collapse_libc_requires
ERROR: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 269, in __getattr__
ERROR:     (self.pkgId,)).fetchone()
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 55, in newFunc
ERROR:     raise Errors.RepoError(str(e))
ERROR: yum.Errors.RepoError: no such column: _collapse_libc_requires
ERROR: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR:   File "/usr/share/createrepo/genpkgmetadata.py", line 308, in <module>
ERROR:     main(sys.argv[1:])
ERROR:   File "/usr/share/createrepo/genpkgmetadata.py", line 276, in main
ERROR:     mdgen.doPkgMetadata()
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/createrepo/__init__.py", line 424, in doPkgMetadata
ERROR:     self.writeMetadataDocs(packages)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/createrepo/__init__.py", line 702, in writeMetadataDocs
ERROR:     save_keptpkgs(pkg)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/createrepo/__init__.py", line 621, in save_keptpkgs
ERROR:     self.primaryfile.write(po.xml_dump_primary_metadata())
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/packages.py", line 1339, in xml_dump_primary_metadata
ERROR:     msg += misc.to_unicode(self._dump_format_items())
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/packages.py", line 1203, in _dump_format_items
ERROR:     msg += self._dump_requires()
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/packages.py", line 1268, in _dump_requires
ERROR:     if hasattr(self, '_collapse_libc_requires') and self._collapse_libc_requires:
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yum/sqlitesack.py", line 273, in __getattr__
ERROR:     raise KeyError(str(e))
ERROR: KeyError: 'no such column: _collapse_libc_requires'
```

---

**Update**

I should have stated that this exception occurs during the installation of a custom rpm. But doesn't appear on every installation.

Comment: If `_collapse_libc_requires` is a variable in your Python code  then why does it appear inside single quotes in `if hasattr(self, '_collapse_libc_requires')`?

Comment: It isn't in my Python code. It appears in the `yum` Python code.
https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/master/yum/packages.py

Comment: Because this is part of the `yum` package manager, which is very robust, my assumption is that this issue is my fault and not a bug found in `yum`

Comment: @forpas After reading your comment again I believe I understand what you are asking. In my post I said that `_collapse_libc_requires` is a variable, but since it is used inside single quotes you are saying that it can't be variable. You are correct, it isn't a variable.